# golang / urfave.cli: can't get to set flags manually

Tags: go, command-line-interface, flags

We have an app which receives an urfave cli context object in a func:

```
import "gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1"

func runApp(ctx *cli.Context) {
   cache := ctx.GlobalInt(MyFlag.Name)
   .... // do more stuff
}
```

I am trying to call `runApp` without the whole cli stuff, directly from code. Hence I have to build the `ctx` manually:

```
func MyTest() {
  fs := flag.NewFlagSet("", flag.ExitOnError)
  app := cli.NewApp()
  fs.Set(MyFlag.Name, "5000")
  ctx := cli.NewContext(app, fs, nil)
  runApp(ctx)
}
```

But it actually looks like the flag is never set, runApp never sees the value I set by hand.

What am I doing wrong? Can this actually be done at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `MyFlag.Name` this field is not actually defined as a flag.
To define it as a flag, you need do this:  `fs.String(MyFlag.Name, "5000", "usageOfTheFlag")`
After this you can use `fs.Set` for `MyFlag.Name`.

```
var MyFlag = flag.Flag{
    Name: "TestFlag",
}

func MyTest() {
  fs := flag.NewFlagSet("", flag.ExitOnError)
  app := cli.NewApp()
  // define a flag with default value
  fs.String(MyFlag.Name, "5000", "usageOfTheFlag")
  // set a new value
  err := fs.Set(MyFlag.Name, "5000")

  if err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
     return
  }

  ctx := cli.NewContext(app, fs, nil)
  runApp(ctx)
}
```

```
func runApp(ctx *cli.Context) {
   cache := ctx.GlobalInt(MyFlag.Name)
   .... // do more stuff
}
```

If you would do an error checking on `fs.Set` with your flag name without define it as a flag:

```
// fs.String(MyFlag.Name, "5000", "usageOfTheFlag")
err := fs.Set(MyFlag.Name, "5000")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

You would get this error with the name of the flag that is currently not defined as a flag.
In this example it is `"TestFlag"`:

```
no such flag -TestFlag
```

Thus `MyFlag.Name` didn't get the new value and because of it your program didn't see your new value.

Comment: Hey this actually brought me a step further. If I just use `fs.String(...)`, however, it doesn't work. I do have to **also** use `fs.Set(...)` for the values to be set and usable. At least that's what worked for me.

Comment: I edited my answer according to it.